# Taking three records from the products in the table according to their categories

Tags: django, dictionary, django-models, orm, django-queryset

I have two tables named categories and products. How can I get three records from each category on the homepage? Thanks in advance

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = ...

class Produc(models.Model):
    name = ...
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, ...

class Home_Cls(TemplateView):
    ...

    def homepro(self):
        cats = Category.objects.all()
        for cat in cats :
            que= Products.objects.filter(
                category_id=cat[..]
            ).order_by('?')[:3]

        return que
```

I tried a little. :( Waiting for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this way by storing in list and returning that list:

```py
class Home_Cls(TemplateView):
    ...

    def homepro(self):
        cats = Category.objects.all()
        que_lst = []
        for cat in cats :
            que_lst.extend(list(Products.objects.filter(category_id=cat[..]).order_by('?')[:3]))

        return que_lst
```

Comment: Thank you. It's what I wanted. But category products appear in the same order, how can I solve this?

Comment: import random -> random.shuffle(que_lst)

Comment: yeah shuffling the list